# Robot Framework Requests Library: set session cookie

Tags: api, python-requests, robotframework

I am trying to create a session using RequestsLibrary in Robot Framework. The first API call is the "authentication step". This step requires that I store a cookie for the remainder of the API calls. Normally, I would use

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d 
"j_username=foo%40inq.com&j_password=pass123&submit=Login" https://api.company.com/j_spring_security_check
```

But as I understand it, RequestsLibrary doesn't support curl commands? Below is an example of the code I'm trying to execute

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       API

Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     Collections
*** Variables ***
${headers}      Create Dictionary    Content-Type    application/json    Accept    application/json
*** Test Cases ***
Tester
Create Session    TC  https://api.company.com/j_spring_security_check?j_username=regression1@att&j_password=TCpass1234&submit=Login  ${headers}  cookies.txt
```

It works if I leave the cookie param as None, but then I am unable to run the remainder of the test:

```
${result}=  Post Request       TC       https://api.company.com/engagementAPI/v1/agent/login?username=regression1@att&password=TCpass1234&output=json     headers = ${headers}
```

The post works, but I'm not getting the desired response as when I run this in Swagger UI

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't appear you did any research before asking this question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: Please show me a link where you have found the answer to my question, or even documentation that would be useful. Event the documentation for Requests Library is a joke: https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/

Comment: RequestsLibrary is just a wrapper around the python [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) package (which it mentions at the very top of the documentation you linked to). I looked through the code of RequestLibrary to see what lower level functions it was calling, and then read the requests documentation to see what that function expected. Plus, I also just searched stackoverflow and found several examples of using RequestsLibrary and cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The `cookies` parameter needs to contain the actual cookies as a dictionary, not a filename.

For example:

```
${cookies}=  Create Dictionary   foo=bar  
Create Session  session  ${url}  cookies=${cookies}
```